# Is there a way to find directory path using regex on cmake?

Tags: regex, cmake, path

I looked up all over but couldn't find an answer for this.

Let's say I have a directory path like this : {MY_PATH}/AAA_unknown_pattern/other/inside/files.../

How can I get path **"{MY_PATH}/AAA_unknown_pattern"** without knowing "**unknown_pattern**" and other inside files;

MY_PATH is known and i also know the directory starts with "AAA_"

I tried something like this using regex but it doesn't work:

`get_filename_component(TEST "${MY_PATH }/^AAA_" DIRECTORY)`

`message("test: ${TEST}")`  shows "C:/path/until/here/^AAA_" instead of correct path.

The reason of all this is because I want to split after and get **unknown_pattern**
.
Thank you.

Comment: The command [get_filename_component](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/command/get_filename_component.html) doesn't accept regex, you can find this out by reading documentation. If you want to list files by globbing, use [file(GLOB)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/command/file.html#glob) command.

Comment: thank you for your answer, it led me good and could figure it out.

I used file
(GLOB TEST RELATIVE ${MY_PATH} ${PLUGINS_DIR}/AAA*)

Now TEST contains the AAA{other_characters} directory name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Tsyvarev I could figure it out using

```
file(GLOB TEST RELATIVE ${MY_PATH} ${MY_PATH}/AAA*)
MESSAGE("TEST=${TEST}")
```

it prints the whole AAA{other_chars} directory name